# Minitest::Spec syntax slow? (compared to ActiveSupport::TestCase)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I've been comparing the run times of writing tests with the normal rails `ActiveSupport::TestCase` versus `Minitest::Spec`

Take the following example:

```
class MyDecoratorTest < Minitest::Spec
  describe('#human_duration') do
    before do
      @runner = build_stubbed(:runner, { status: 'completed', duration: 121 })
      @decorator = MyDecorator.new(@booking)
    end

    it('is TBA when #completed? falsey') do
      @decorator.stubs({ completed?: false })
      assert_equal('TBA', @decorator.human_duration)
    end

    it('is properly displayed when #compelted? truthy') do
      assert_equal('121 min (2 hours and 1 min)', @decorator.human_duration)
    end
  end
end
```

versus

```
class MyDecoratorTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @runner = build_stubbed(:runner, { status: 'completed', duration: 121 })
    @decorator = MyDecorator.new(@booking)
  end

  test('is TBA when #completed? falsey') do
    @decorator.stubs({ completed?: false })
    assert_equal('TBA', @decorator.human_duration)
  end

  test('is properly displayed when #completed truthy') do
    assert_equal('121 min (2 hours and 1 min)', @decorator.human_duration)
  end
end
```

`Minitest::Spec` completes in ~ 0.9s

`ActiveSupport::TestCase` completes in ~ 0.4s

The disparity is so large, I don't feel inclined to do a proper bench...but I'm wondering if/how I should go about that *and* if this is similar to other experiences on the internet???

Comment: The difference seems rather insignificant to me. I feel like the "difference" is also likely due to something else. For example, perhaps the disk happened to be busy on one run, and took 0.5s to unblock before reading the file for execution.

Comment: You mean visually? Or you ran a similar test and it’s indistinguishable. The times I shared were repeatable and not a one-off.

Comment: add `class Foo < Minitest::Spec; end` to bottom of the `ActiveSupport` test and `class Foo < ActiveSupport::TestCase; end` to the bottom of the `Minitest::Spec` test. What are the average runtimes then? Is there any spring caching going on?

Comment: @Kache, runtimes are comparable. I can only assume that the run time is due to metaprogramming building tests cases from Spec -> TestCase? I'd probably be better off having a split suite w/ rspec.

Comment: I've experienced the same thing!

On a class with 50 tests / 203 assertion:

- describe style --> ~ 65sec
- test style --> ~16sec

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti yeah; I just don't have the time/interest to dive deep into this, but there are some obvious drawbacks. I recall zenspider _somewhere_ saying, whether at a conference or in github, that this was a possible extension to minitest, but not preferred for these reasons.

Comment: @KevinBrown I see... what a pity!